# Perl: Get key value

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to get key values from hash inside my module:

**Module.pm**

```
...
my $logins_dump = "tmp/logins-output.txt";
system("cat /var/log/secure | grep -n -e 'Accepted password for' > $logins_dump");
open (my $fh, "<", $logins_dump) or die "Could not open file '$logins_dump': $!";

sub UserLogins {
    my %user_logins;
    while (my $array = <$fh>) {
        if ($array =~ /Accepted\s+password\s+for\s+(\S+)/) {
            $user_logins{$1}++;
         }
    }
    return \%user_logins;
}

sub CheckUserLogins {
    my $LoginCounter;
    my $UsersToCheck = shift @_;
    if (exists %{UserLogins()}{$UsersToCheck}){
        $LoginCounter = %{UserLogins{$UsersToCheck}}; #How many logins?
    }
    else {
        $LoginCounter = "0";
    }
    return \$LoginCounter;
}
```

**Script.pl**

```
$UserLoginCounter = Module::CheckUserLogins($UsersToPass);
```

I pass usernames to script and check if username is in hash, if it is, I need to return number of logins, which I'm trying to do with `$LoginCounter`. For some reason scripts returns only 0 or undef.

Comment: I see no subroutine called `CheckLoginAttempts`. But bear in mind `return \$LoginCounter;` returns a reference, not the value. And also - `exists` will still work if it's `undef`.

Comment: Misspelled routine name, fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters - you've got `CheckUserLogins` not `CheckLoginAttempts`.

Assuming that's just a typo - `UserLogins` returns a hash reference - a single scalar value. You're getting `0` if the `exists` check fails presumably.

If it *does* exist though, you're doing this:

```
$LoginCounter = %{UserLogins{$UsersToCheck}};
```

Which isn't valid. Do you have `strict` and `warnings` turned on? Because you're trying to assign a hash to a scalar, which isn't going to do what you want.

You probably mean:

```
$LoginCounter = ${UserLogins()} -> {$UsersToCheck};
```

Which dereferences the reference from `UserLogins` and then looks up a key.

I might however, approach your problem a little differently - it'll only work once when you do what you're doing, because each time you call `UserLogins` it creates a new hash, but you *don't* rewind `$fh`.

So I'd suggest:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my %userlogins;

    sub inituserlogins {
        open( my $fh, "<", '/var/log/secure' )
            or die "Could not open file: $!";
        while ( my $array = <$fh> ) {
            if ( $array =~ /Accepted\s+password\s+for\s+(\S+)/ ) {
                $userlogins{$1}++;
            }
        }
        close($fh);
    }

    sub CheckUserLogins {
        my ($UsersToCheck) = @_;
        inituserlogins() unless %userlogins;
        return $userlogins{$UsersToCheck} ? $userlogins{$UsersToCheck} : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I wrote earlier, misspelled subroutine name. Yes, `strict` and `warnings` are in every script. Get no errors though. Will try it now.

Comment: There's no point in the `close` as the file handle is lexical. And anyway it should be `close($fh)`. The name of the handle in your `open` is also wrong

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't use capital letters in lexical identifiers as Perl reserves them for global identifiers like package names

One of the main problems is that you're using

```
exists %{UserLogins()}{$UsersToCheck}
```

which should be

```
exists UserLogins()->{$UsersToCheck}
```

or

```
exists ${UserLogins()}{$UsersToCheck}
```

Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in place as you should have?

Another problem is that you will read all the way through the file every time you call `UserLogins`. That means the second and later calls to `CheckUserLogins` (which calls `UserLogins`) will find nothing, as the end of the file has been reached

You should call your suibroutine `user_logins` and call it just *once*, storing the result as a scalar variable. This program shows how

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;  # For state variables

sub user_logins {

    open my $fh, '<', '/var/log/secure' or die $!;

    my %user_logins;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        if ( /Accepted\s+password\s+for\s+(\S+)/ ) {
            ++$user_logins{$1};
        }
    }

    \%user_logins;
}

sub check_user_logins {
    my ($users_to_check) = @_;
    state $user_logins = user_logins();
    $user_logins->{$users_to_check} // 0;
}
```

Comment: Does that first declaration need a `%` rather than a `$`? Or a deref afterwards?

Comment: @Sobrique: You're right; the access to the hash should be indirect. Thanks